# Como criar um bloco vazio?

Tags: html, css, div, empty

Como faço para criar um bloco VAZIO+TRANSPARENTE de 800px de altura por 1000px de largura? 
E porque o código abaixo não funciona para isso?

**html**

```
<div class="block"></div>
```

**css**

```
.block {
 height: 800px;
 width: 1000px;
}
```

Com isso, estou tentando criar espaços acima e abaixo da div `.vitrine`:

```
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="vitrine"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: o código que você postou funciona, você quer ele transparente ? pra que ?

Comment: dá uma olhada: http://jsfiddle.net/qnF3p/

Comment: Por exemplo, para criar uma área vazia. Mas também para conhecer mais sobre html e css. Por volta dos anos 2000 eu usava um gif transparente para as células ganharem o tamanho que eu queria. Achava eu que isso não era mais necessário.

Comment: boa, com o background-color funciona. eu posso usar um opacity depois para deixar transparente. A cor, ou algum preenchimento fazer a vez do gif transparente. Curioso. Valeu!

Comment: sem background-color também funciona, dá uma olhada: http://jsfiddle.net/qnF3p/3/

Comment: que estranho. não funciona com o código abaixo...
queria criar um espaço antes e depois da div vitrine

<body>  
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="vitrine"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>  
</body>

-------

.vitrine {
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #222;
}

.block {
  height: 800x;
}

Comment: falta um "p" na altura da class block - .block { height: 800px; } http://jsfiddle.net/qnF3p/4/

Comment: esse p agora não estava no código, mas realmente funciona o que eu escrevi lá em cima. Valeu pela ajuda!

Answer (score 3):

Você não precisa de elementos invisíveis para criar esses espaços. No caso do seu último exemplo, simplesmente aplique margens na div `.vitrine`:

```
<div class="vitrine"></div>
```

```
.vitrine { 
    height: 350px; 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: #222; 
    margin-top: 800px;
    margin-bottom: 800px;
}
```

Dá para simplificar o CSS das margens também:

```
margin: 800px 0; /* top/bottom = 800px, left/right = 0 */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bL9qG/

Comment: Perfeito, funciona neste caso que citei acima. Mas suponha que a vitrine se repita em outro momento da página onde não deve haver os 800px?

Comment: Nesse caso, as margens não pertenceriam à vitrine mesmo. Mas podem pertencer a algum outro elemento. Meu ponto é que hoje em dia dificilmente você precisa usar um elemento invisível como espaçador. Se quiser, atualize sua pergunta com um exemplo concreto e mais completo do problema, e eu atualizo a resposta com uma sugestão mais direcionada.

Comment: Não tenho nada concreto em mente, estou entendendo como funcionam algumas relações para poder brincar um pouco. Tava criando isso aqui http://www.arslab.com.br/lab/effects/compliance/teste.php

Comment: Entendi. Nesse caso parece fazer sentido seu bloco ali mesmo. Eu criaria 3 classes em vez de uma (bloco simples, duplo e triplo). E você pode combinar classes e deixar os nomes mais semânticos. Poderia ter `<div class="triplo transparente"></div>`. Isso poderia ser usado com todas as cores.